# Данные за текущий месяц, текущую неделю, предыдущий месяц

Tags: дата, mysql

Как в mysql вывести

1. данные за текущий месяц
2. данные за текущую неделю
3. данные за предыдущий месяц

Comment: Где названия таблиц, полей, где ваши пробные запросы??? Пока на ваш вопрос ответ один - написать mysql запрос!

Comment: Зачем всё это?    
Проще написать:   

      ... WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())

Comment: Кстати, это выводятся данные за текущий месяц.

Comment: А если

    ... WHERE WEEK('date') = WEEK(NOW()) AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())

не работает? Такой оператор как бы тоже [имеется][1]


  [1]: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: А за прошлый месяц:

    ... WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())-1 AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())

правда могут быть проблемы с январем...

Comment: ну так убери год :) проблема исчезнет)

Comment: @thunder, как она исчезнет? MONTH(январь) - 1 = 0, а MONTH(декабрь) = 12

Comment: WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW())-1

оно само пересчитает, если будет декабрь предыдущего года.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Нашел информацию: 
Данные за текущий месяц

```
... WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Данные за текущую неделю

```
... WHERE YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW()) AND WEEK(`date`, 1) = WEEK(NOW(), 1)
```

Данные за предыдущий месяц

```
... WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(NOW())
```

Answer (score 2):

С данными за предыдущий месяц будут проблемы, если текущий месяц январь, лучше так:

```
... WHERE MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) and YEAR(`date`) = YEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```